# get field of constructor by reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a string array like this:

```
namespace DynamicCore
{
    public class DynamicCode
    {
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        public DynamicCode()
        {
            List<Variable> variableList = new List<Variable>();
            Variable Variable = new Variable();

            Variable.ID = "Variable_26545789";
            Variable.Name = "var1";
            variableList_Process_1.Add(Variable);

            Variable = new Variable();

            Variable.ID = "Variable_vdvd3679";
            Variable.Name = "var2";    

            variableList_Process_1.Add(Variable);
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it using `CompileAssemblyFromSource` like this (`GetCode` gets string array) and store class in **Memory**:

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, GetCode());
```

I need to get `variableList` and show `Variable.Name` items in a listbox. I tested `GetFields` and `GetProperty` but none was not working properly.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to get variableList and show Variable.Name items in a listbox. I tested GetFields and GetProperty but none was not working properly.

Both `variableList` and `Variable` are **local** variables. They *don't* live outside the scope of `DynamicCode()` constructor.

Declare them as fields or properties in the `DynamicCode` class.